# How to allow Visual Studio Validate {$Something} in html editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, intellisense, jtemplates

In Visual Studio HTML Editor (aspx webform / mvc) i have some code:

```
<tr id="${PropertyKey}">
  <td title="DataModeHtml">
     <input type="checkbox" ${DataModeHtml} value="${DataModeKey}"/>
  </td>
  <td title="PropertyCode">
    ${PropertyCode}
  </td>
</tr>
```

I use jTemplates to render `${DataModeHtml}` to `[checked='checked']` or `[string.Empty]`.
All okie, but Visual Studio "Warning" in editor Error List: "Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'DataModeHtml' is not a valid attribute of element 'input'."

How can we: setting in visual studio, create add-on or add something to xsd-xml IntelliSense VS to solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Need to declare custom tags in the Intellisense files.

See [this article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172653.aspx) and scroll down to **IntelliSense for custom tags**